# How do i read the URL using PHP (which is the url returned in browser)

Tags: php

http://www.local.com/?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I want to retrieve and save code parameter in PHP

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try this

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
```

now `$code` will have value of code which is in url

Comment: welcome, one more thing you can use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work:

```
<?php $code = $_GET['code']; ?>
```

`$code` should now have the `code` in the URL.

For more information on `$_GET`, see [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).